# How to convert a string dictionary to dictionary in python?

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have dictionary in form of string -

`dict_in_str = '{"name":"wrong_answers","y":8,"color": colorForSections["wrong_answers"]}'`

I have tried both, the `json.loads(dict_in_str)` and `ast.literal_eval(dict_in_str)` methods.

But both of them are giving

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 40 (char 39)`

and

`ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Subscript object at 0x02082B20>`

respectively. On forums and tutorials I have looked upon these methods seems to work.

Comment: You don't have a literal, your "dictionary" involves a variable and key lookup. You'd need `eval` for that, as it must run actual code. Which is a bad idea…

Comment: Assuming `colorForSections["wrong_answers"]` is even a defined variable, which, if the string is copied from somewhere else might not even be the case.

Comment: @RNAY, you asked about this in another (now closed) question, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by deceze and matszwejca, he issue is your value in your last part, "color": colorForSections["wrong_answers"]. It can't evaluate the value of 'colorForSections["wrong_answers"]' because it's in a string. When you run loads() on it, it can't convert it to any known type (I'm assuming that's what's going on, egg on my face if not). Try passing in the key string ("wrong_answers") and then retrieving the value from colorForSections after you run loads() on the string. Something like:

```
dict_in_str = '{"name":"wrong_answers","y":8,"color": "wrong_answers"}'
x = json.loads(dict_in_str)
color = colorForSections[x['color']]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Your solution is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace and split into list and then convert into dict.

```
dict_in_str = '{"name":"wrong_answers","y":8,"color": 
colorForSections["wrong_answers"]}'
data_lst = dict_in_str.replace("'", '').replace('"', '').replace('{', 
'').replace('}', '').replace(':', ',').split(',')
lst = [i.strip() for i in data_lst if i.strip()]
result = {lst[i]: lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)}
print(result)
print(type(result))

>>> {'name': 'wrong_answers', 'y': '8', 'color': 'colorForSections[wrong_answers]'}
```

> > > <class 'dict'>